# On mac (Chrome and Safari), words look bolder than on PC, why?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, operating-system

When reviewing on different OS's, I noticed that particularly in Chrome and Safari, words on a mac book look bolder than on a PC. Isn't it true that only browser web-kits have the capability of interpreting CSS and HTML, not an OS itself?

Here is my CSS for the anchor tags (words) if the above case isn't valid:

```
.homeText .cases {
    color: #bcbcbc;
    float:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 2.65em;
    font-weight:bolder;
    line-height: 30px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    padding-right: 13px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is due to differences in the text-rendering algorithms used by each OS. [This article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html) provides a detailed explanation with examples for comparison.

Comment: and the implementing of font-weight:bolder; differs from browser to browser

Comment: I found that this CSS fixes the bolder font on the Mac:

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;   
    /* This needs to be set or some font faced fonts look bold on Mac. */ 

but not evidently for Firefox on mac.

Answer (score 2):

OS X isn't changing the CSS or boldness of the text.  It uses different font rendering and smoothing algorithms for displaying text, so text usually appears "fatter" on OS X than on Windows.  [Here's one site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html) that talks about it.  Googling "OS X font smoothing" will give you lots of results.