# Font appear to be stronger on dark background

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts, roboto

I'm trying to get around a irritating issue with fonts. Specific Googles Roboto font.

The thing is that the font appear to be stronger (fat) on dark backgrounds in my tests (Chrome 62.0.3202.62 on OSX Sierra 10.12.6) while it play nice on googles dark font edition (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:300,500,700 - Choose dark background).

Screenshot of my appearing:

[image]

vs Google appearing (its the light)

[image]

I started to belive there was something wrong with my rendering, but after trying this on several machines with different setup, its all the same.

Do anyone have any idea of how to fix this? Or an explanation of why its different between Google and my test.

Url for testing:
https://jsfiddle.net/fb3umv2e/

```
.btn {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 7px 8px;
   text-align: center;
   background: #fff;
   color: #000;
   font-family: "Roboto";
   font-weight: 300;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 .btn.inverted {
   background: #222;
   color: #fff;
 }
```

Best regards
Richard

Comment: Could you try adding these to your button styling? 

    `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874303/on-mac-chrome-and-safari-words-look-bolder-than-on-pc-why

Comment: @Laura That did the trick. Thanx.

Comment: @Laura Would you add the answer to the question so i might accept it?

Comment: No problem! I have added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these to your button styling :)

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```